# Why the program becomes slow when the number of threads increase

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I'm a Beginner of java.

Recently, I'm writing a program to calculate matrix multiplication. So I write a class to do this.

```java
public class MultiThreadsMatrixMultipy{
 public   int[][] multipy(int[][] matrix1,int[][] matrix2) {
     if(!utils.CheckDimension(matrix1,matrix2)){
         return null;
     }
     int row1 = matrix1.length;
     int col1 = matrix1[0].length;
     int row2 = matrix2.length;
     int col2 = matrix2[0].length;
     int[][] ans = new int[row1][col2];
     Thread[][]  threads = new SingleRowMultipy[row1][col2];

     for(int i=0;i<row1;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<col2;j++){
             threads[i][j] = new SingleRowMultipy(i,j,matrix1,matrix2,ans));
             threads[i][j].start();
         }
     }
     return ans;
 }
}
```

```java
public class SingleRowMultipy extends Thread{
        private int row;
        private int col;
        private int[][] A;
        private int[][] B;
        private int[][] ans;
        public SingleRowMultipy(int row,int col,int[][] A,int[][] B,int[][] C){
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.A = A;
            this.B = B;
            this.ans = C;
        }
        public void run(){
            int sum =0;
            for(int i=0;i<A[row].length;i++){
                 sum+=(A[row][i]*B[i][col]);
            }
            ans[row][col] = sum;
        }
}
```

I want to use a thread to calculate `matrix1[i][:] * matrix2[:][j]`, and the size of the matrix is `1000*5000` and `5000*1000`, so the number of threads is 1000*1000.When I run this program, it's super slow and it will cost about `38s`. If I just use the `single-thread` to calculate the result, it will cost `17s`. The single-threads code is below:

```java
public class SimpleMatrixMultipy
{
    public int[][] multipy(int[][] matrix1,int[][] matrix2){
        int row1 = matrix1.length;
        int col1 = matrix1[0].length;
        int row2 = matrix2.length;
        int col2 = matrix2[0].length;
        int[][] ans = new int[row1][col2];
        for(int i=0;i<row1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col2;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<col1;k++){
                    ans[i][j] += matrix1[i][k]*matrix2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

}
```

What can I do to speed up the program?

Comment: The parallelism is too fine-grained. Thread creation consumes time and memory. Try to limit the number of threads to a reasonable amount, e.g. something between 4 and 32 threads. Also, since the second matrix is accessed column-wise, it may be beneficial to transpose the second matrix or store it in col-major instead of row-major format to increase locality (i.e. caching). Look up "matrix tiling" for an optimized, parallel matrix multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I use a ThreadPool and the size of ThreadPool is 20.The program becomes faster a lot.:)

Comment: The optimal number of threads is the same as number of logical processors in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Turing85 said need to manage threads counts. There are two ways either use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` with fixed number of threads or use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` to use existing thread as available.

Other important point is to avoid inheriting `Thread` class directly, implement runnable instead.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class MultiThreadsMatrixMultipy {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    }

    public int[][] multipy(final int[][] matrix1, final int[][] matrix2) {
        if(!utils.CheckDimension(matrix1,matrix2)){
            return null;
        }
        final int row1 = matrix1.length;
        final int col2 = matrix2[0].length;
        final int[][] ans = new int[row1][col2];
        // final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new CustomThreadFactory("Multiplier"));
        final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20, new CustomThreadFactory("Multiplier"));

        for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
                executor.execute(new SingleRowMultipy(i, j, matrix1, matrix2, ans));
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

class CustomThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private int counter;
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> stats;

    public CustomThreadFactory(final String name) {
        counter = 1;
        this.name = name;
        stats = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread(runnable, name + "-Thread_" + counter);
        counter++;
        stats.add(String.format("Created thread %d with name %s on %s \n", t.getId(), t.getName(), new Date()));
        return t;
    }

    public String getStats() {
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        final Iterator<String> it = stats.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            buffer.append(it.next());
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}

class SingleRowMultipy implements Runnable {
    private final int row;
    private final int col;
    private final int[][] A;
    private final int[][] B;
    private final int[][] ans;

    public SingleRowMultipy(final int row, final int col, final int[][] A, final int[][] B, final int[][] C) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.ans = C;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A[row].length; i++) {
            sum += (A[row][i] * B[i][col]);
        }
        ans[row][col] = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!I understand why I should manager threads counts.But I don't know the reason of implementing runnable instead of inheriting Thread class.Could you tell me why?:)

Comment: @TangDH It has nothing do do with performance, however a good practice. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java for the ans.